# c++ template class member specialization and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-function, template-classes

I would like to write down a set of classes in which there are:

- a pure virtual class that wraps an object of any kind and the relate getter for it.
- one or more classes for every kind of object I need, extending the virtual one and overriding the getter in order to specialize it.

A template class solution for the wrapper seems to fit the case but I have to use it in two different contexts:

- the first one is not aware of wrapper implementations. In this case I should  declare a `Wrapper<AnyObj> var;` with `AnyObj` standing for any class name (like `?` in Java). As far as I know, you can't do this in c++.
- the second one is restricted to a particular wrapper implementation. In this case I need the getter to return the wrapped object with the exact type (rather than downcasting it).

If I'm right I cannot use a template class and, moreover, the wrapper won't have a `protected: T* wrappedObject` member.

I don't know if I'm stuck in the Java approach, wrongly thinking from the beginning, or missing something.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: "As far as I know, you can't do this in c++." .. You mean something like this: `template < typename T > class Wrapper { public: Wrapper(const T& t) : m_obj(t) {} T* getObj() { return &m_obj; } protected: T m_obj; };`? Then to derive it (as you mention): `class IntDerived : public virtual Wrapper <int> { public: IntDerived(int v) : Wrapper<int>(v) {} };` .. But, `pure virtual class` and `one or more classes for every kind of object I need` coupled with `templates` sounds like you've got other design concerns. As another comment said, what problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pure virtual class". Maybe you meant abstract class?

Comment: @txtechhelp thank you for the comment. The code you posted is the solution I tried before but what I still can't do is to use the syntax `Wrapper var = specializationContext.getWrapper();` when I need it in the first of the two contexts i mentioned. I found that I could use the `Wrapper<> var;` form if I declared `template <typename T = int>` class Wrapper ...` but it's like using a `<int>` specialization (not the generic) and it could be dangerous. I wrote the question because I know that the template pattern could not be suitable for this case.

Comment: I did not give you anything. You're assuming too much. I have not voted on this question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You're right, my apologies